# how to determine complexity of a recursive function

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, space-complexity

I have learned the basics of how to determine complexity of recursive function. I can compute some simple problems like,

`f(n) = f(n/2) + c or f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) +c`

But I'm stuck in a problem, which seems a bit different. My recursive function :

```
 ll fun(ll n, ll k = 1) {
  ll res = 1;
  if (k % n == 0)
    return res;
  else {
    res = fun(n, (k * 10 + 1) % n);
    return res + 1;
  }
}
```

Now I have to determine the both time complexity and space complexity of this recursive function. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: In the *worst* case it will never stop at all: `n = 5, k = 1` we get `k == (k * 10 + 1) % n == (5 * 10 + 1) % n == 1` an we loop for ever.

Comment: If we *guaranteed* that arguments are such that `fun` will stop, thrn in the worst case we'll get all possible remainders for `k % n` until we get `0` so we have `O(n)`

Comment: According to the problem, the value of n won't be divided by 5 or 2. And k is always 1.

Comment: The best case is *all ones* `n`, `n = 1111..11` it takes `1` operations for `n = 1`, `2` operations for `n = 11`, `p` operations for `n = 111..11 (p ones)` so the best case is *logarithmic* `O(log(n))`. Finally, best case is `O(log(n))`, best case is linear `O(n)` (worst case `n` must be prime number, but not all primes are worst case values; some examples are `n = 7, 17, 109, 1019, 10007`)